# Bash script error when trying to create a snapshot

Tags: bash, freebsd, zfs, snapshot

I am trying to create a snapshot using Bash script as below but error occurred.

Environment: FreeBSD,
Version: 13.2,
Script: Bash

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
name="17102023_1234"
zfs snapshot data/library@$name
```

run this simple bash script but received error as shown below.

**' in named character ' 'data/library@17102023_1234**

It works when I put '17102023_1234' after @ instead of variable.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Check your script for dos style line breaks

Comment: Hi Gerald. I don't understand what you mean.